# Ways of choosing an event

Tags: probability

A shipper of 10 TV sets includes three that are defective. In how many ways can a hotel purchase these sets and receive at least two of the defective.

I'm a bit confused about what the problem is asking, some help.

Comment: Sorry for the mispelling. It is 4 sets of those 10, and get at least 2 defectiv

Answer (score 0):

If the customer is to buy 4 sets and get at least 2 defective, he can get exactly 2 defective by buying 2 of the 3 defective, which can be selected in ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ ways and the other 2 can be selected from the 7 good ones in ${7 \choose 2}=$ how many? ways.  Then multiply these to get the number of ways to get 2 defective and 2 good ones.  Add to this the number of ways to get 3 defective and 1 good one and you are done.